# I am finding an parse error

Tags: php, parsing

I am finding an parse error in my code tried to find but nothing is possible for me please help to find out this pase error.

```
<?php
//allow sessions to be passed so we can see if the user is logged in
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){


include "./db.php";
//connect to the database so we can check, edit, or insert data to our users table
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_connect_errno());
//$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con) or die(mysql_error());

//include out functions file giving us access to the protect() function made earlier
include "./functions.php";
include('header.php');
include "./loadmore.php";
 ?>

<style type="text/css">
body {
font: normal 13px arial,sans-serif;
}
.email_list{ 
margin-bottom:20px;
}
div.list_item {
border-left: 4px solid #7ad03a;
padding: 1px 12px;
background-color:#F1F1F1;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
div.list_item {
margin: 5px 15px 2px;
}
div.list_item p {
margin: .5em 0;
padding: 2px;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.5;
}
.list_item a {
text-decoration: none;
padding-bottom: 2px;
color: #0074a2;
-webkit-transition-property: border,background,color;
transition-property: border,background,color;-webkit-transition-duration: .05s;
transition-duration: .05s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.list_item a:hover{ 
text-decoration:underline;
}
.show_more_main {
margin: 15px 25px;
}
.show_more {
background-color: #f8f8f8;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fcfcfc 0,#f8f8f8 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(top,#fcfcfc 0,#f8f8f8 100%);
border: 1px solid;
border-color: #d3d3d3;
color: #333;
font-size: 12px;
outline: 0;
}
.show_more {
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
padding: 10px 0;
text-align: center;
font-weight:bold;
}
.loding {
background-color: #e9e9e9;
border: 1px solid;
border-color: #c6c6c6;
color: #333;
font-size: 12px;
display: block;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px 0;
outline: 0;
font-weight:bold;
}
.loding_txt {
background-image: url(loading_16.gif);
background-position: left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: 0;
display: inline-block;
height: 16px;
padding-left: 20px;
}

</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.show_more').hide();
        $('.loding').show();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajax_more.php',
            data:'id='+ID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
                $('.tutorial_list').append(html);
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>

            <div>
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">E-mails </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="row-fluid sortable">    
                <div class="box span12">
                    <div class="box-header well" data-original-title>
                        <h2>Get Active Emails List</h2>
                        <div class="box-icon">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-setting btn-round"><i class="icon-cog"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-minimize btn-round"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
                              <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                      <th>Emails</th>
                                  </tr>
                              </thead>   
                              <tbody>
                                    <?php getActiveSendListEmails($con);?>

                              </tbody>
                         </table> 
                         <?php
                        //get rows query
                            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM emails where status=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25");

                        //number of rows
                            $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);

                        if($rowCount > 0){ 
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
                                 $tutorial_id =     $row['id'];
                                ?> } 
                                <?php 
                        // line number 162 is most culprit line but i am not getting what shoud do.. 
<div class="show_more_main" id="show_more_main <?php getActiveSendListEmails($con); ?> ">
                                       //<span id="<?php echo getActiveSendListEmails($con); ?>" class="show_more" title="Load more posts">Show more</span>
                                    <span class="loding" style="display: none;"><span class="loding_txt">Loading...</span></span>
                                </div>
                        ?> }
                    </div>


                </div><!--/span-->
                </div>



<?php include('footer.php');} else
{ 
echo 'Not authorised.... <a href="login.php">Login</a>';
} ?>
```

t redirecting but not giving me my result back. am i doing it right. i am getting inout by  and matching it with the available name inside database then i am fetching array and after that i am assigning it to session. than displaying back. M i doing it right ? –

Comment: what error? state that and format you code. It seems broken

Comment: Checkout your php error log / commandline output / debugger output to get the location of your parse error. Or at least an error message and update your question with that information.

Comment: lots of mistake with php open tag and close tag  like this  *?> }  <?php*

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot wrong with your code. First:

`?> } <?php // line number 162 is most culprit line but i am not getting what shoud do..`

There's also this one

`"> //" class="show_more" title="Load more posts">Show more Loading... ?> }`

You seem to be closing your php braces outside of php code blocks instead.

We don't even know what your line 162 looks like.

Fix *those lines* and then you might have your code fixed.